# Retrieve Twilio messages by date range?

Tags: twilio

I'm a bit of a php/twilio newb so excuse my ignorance in advance :)

I'm trying to get a list of messages in Twilio within a date rate. When I do the call as expected, it keeps getting ALL of my messages.

i.e.

```
$messages = $twilio->messages
                   ->read(array(
                       "dateSent" => new \DateTime('2018-8-31'),
                   );
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving all messages? I believe you get all messages sent that day with this call. Which versions of the library/API are you using?

Comment: It's definitely getting all the messages. Not sure which version o the API - it was downloaded in February 2018. Any easy way to check?